# Javapackager disable autostart?

Tags: java, autostart

Using Java 8 included javapackager tool for creating an exe file which works fine and can be used for installing the javaFX application afterwards BUT anyone know how to disable that the application autostart after installed is finished? Haven't been able to find such an option for javapackager?

Comment: What do you mean by "autostart"?  Are you talking about the Windows autostart?  If so ... http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/how-to-disable-an-auto-start-program-within/3469b847-5174-4fa5-8918-6ddcabb2426b?auth=1

Comment: Mean that after the installation is done, sure it could be windows autostart, but right now the application that is just installed is also started directly after installation done!